# Проблемы кнопок поделиться на мобильных устройствах

Tags: jquery

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: поставив кнопки поделиться на сайт, заметил что с мобильных устройств при нажатии на кнопку происходит переход на мобильные версии соц.сетей, в процессе которого слетает ссылка, которой делюсь, или ее кодировка. Как можно кодировать ссылки при передачи в соц сети, или отменить переход и отслеживать мобильные устройства и открывать окно страницы поделиться соц сетей сразу в мобильной версии?

```
    go: function(_element, _options) {
        var
            self = Share,
            options = $.extend(
                {
                    type:       'vk, fb, gp, tw',     // тип соцсети
                    url:        location.href,  // какую ссылку шарим
                    title:      $('meta[name=title]').attr('content'),
                    image:      $('meta[name=image]').attr('content'), 
                    text:       $('meta[name=descr]').attr('content')
                },
                $(_element).data(),
                _options
            );

        if (self.popup(link = self[options.type](options)) === null) {
            if ( $(_element).is('a') ) {
                $(_element).prop('href', link);
                return true;
            }
            else {
                location.href = link;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    },
fb: function(_options) {
    var options = $.extend({
        url:    location.href,
        title:  document.title,
        image:  '',
        text:   ''
    }, _options);
    return 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100'
        + '&p[title]='     + encodeURIComponent(options.title)
        + '&p[summary]='   + encodeURIComponent(options.text)
        + '&p[url]='       + encodeURIComponent(options.url)
        + '&p[images][0]=' + encodeURIComponent(options.image)

};
```

Comment: Так может это недочет соцсетей, что они теряют информацию при переходе на свои мобильные версии? Попробуйте просто в браузере на мобильном (или с юзерагентом мобильного телефона)  открыть одну из ссылок генерируемых скриптом.

Comment: открыл, происходит следующее, как только ссылка доходит до открывающейся скобки [ весь, идущий после нее текст теряется, как-то можно заставить браузеры читать эти скобки как часть ссылки?

Comment: Если речь о fb, то есть такой ответ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956229/has-facebook-sharer-php-changed-to-no-longer-accept-detailed-parameters#22969530 в котором сказано, что в sharer.php больше не поддерживаются пользовательские параметры и рекомендуется использовать dialog/feed